# Do any heroes share romantic relationships with other heroes?

Tags: overwatch

I'm curious if there are any official OTP in Overwatch.  Specifically, is there any hero who has a romantic relationship or interest in another hero?

I know that Widowmaker looks up to Reaper, but I'm not sure if she was romantically involved with him.  Do Tracer and Winston have a thing going on? Or are they just friends?

What relationships are there, if any, romantically in Overwatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No heroes are in romantic relationships with any other heroes according to current canon.  That said, several heroes have romantic relationships with non-hero characters.

- We know that Tracer is in a romantic relationship with a woman named [Emily](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Emily) (as shown in comics)
- Widowmaker was married to a man named [Gérard Lacroix](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/G%C3%A9rard_Lacroix) (whom she killed whilst basically brainwashed)
- Torbjörn is married to a woman named [Ingrid Lindholm](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ingrid_Lindholm), and his daughter is Brigitte (he also has several other children and grandchildren that are unnamed)
- Ana is married to (or has some other romantic relationship with, hasn't been confirmed they're actually married) a man named [Sam](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Sam).

Beyond that, no other characters have known canon romantic relationships.  Some characters are related (other than friendship) in a number of ways though to other heroes and non-heroes.

- Pharah is Ana and Sam's daughter
- Brigitte is Torbjörn's daughter and Reinhardt is her godfather
- Genji and Hanzo are brothers
- Winston has an adoptive father, [Harold Winston](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Harold_Winston)
- Orisa was created by [Efi Oladele](https://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Efi_Oladele) in response to an attack from Doomfist

All other known canon relations between characters are friends, neutral, or enemies.  At the moment, there are no other familial relationships that have been revealed.  That said, some of the friendships are strong (Tracer and Winston are very good friends, Ana and Reinhardt seem to be good friends, and Junkrat and Roadhog are close friends, for example).  As are some of the rivalries (obvious ones are Doomfist v Orisa and Soldier v Reaper, though the latter two were once close associates and presumably friends).

Answer (score 6):

Nothing is explicitly mentioned in canon. The closest thing you might find is D.Va and Lucio being fans of each other, but from there to any romantic interest it's a big leap.

Comment: This is technically the correct lore answer.

Answer (score 0):

Genji and mercy may have a relationship because in the valentine voice lines they talked about sharing chocolates. This could be a start of something. Another thing is when mercy revives Genji, Genji calls her by her first name.

Answer (score 0):

Luico and D.va have something between each other hinting by voice lines Genji and Mercy have a voice line tracer and winston are friends Ana and Soldier through they have some voice lines hinting to a relationship but I do not want to get ahead of myself reaper and widow probably have something going on but then again widow does not feel emotions maybe they did not brain wash all her emotions or the effect wore off once she killed he husband Zarya (pre becoming a hero of russia) fought omnics in her spare time so definitely no relation with a omnic